# What is the unit of the output of a sounddevice recording?

Tags: python, python-sounddevice

Is it in volts, decibels, or something else? I need the units in order to label the y-axis of a plot of the sound wave. I tried looking up documentation but couldn't find any information about units.

To be more specific, I want to know the units for the output of this function.

```
recording=sd.rec(time*sample_rate, channels=1,samplerate=sample_rate,blocking=True)
```

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.15/)? Can you please show the relevant code you are using which results in the output of which you want to know the unit?

Comment: I'd go with arbitrary units if I were in you. You should probably ask the manufacturer of the device, rather than us, to have a slight chance of getting it correct.

Comment: But most likely the values will be on a relative scale and to find out to which voltage (measured at which point?) they correspond, you would need to know the exact details of the actual audio hardware and DAC used to record the signal.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited in the relevant code. I did look at the website you linked, but it didn't  contain any information about units.

Comment: My question was (and still is): Is the website I linked to (a) the documentation *of the library you are using*, or is it (b) the documentation of something entirely unrelated?

Comment: @norok2 mkrieger1 Ah, okay. I thought sounddevice would normalize the input to some unit, but if it's a matter of my computer's audio hardware I'll take norok's suggestion and just leave the units arbitrary then.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's the correct library.